# Is there a way to exit/end old recursions (function()) without finishing them?

Tags: python

I created a very short program that forces the `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while pickling an object` to occur:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(1)

AB,CD=0,0

def A():
    global AB
    AB+=1
    print('A',AB,CD)
    # End all () except for A
    B()
    print('A2')

def B():
    global AB
    AB+=1
    print('B')
    C()
    print('B2')

def C():
    global CD
    CD+=1
    print('C')
    D()
    A()
    print('D2')

def D():
    global CD
    CD+=1
    print('D')

A()
```

What you will get in shell is:

```
A 1 0
B
C
#<...> (a couple of lines that I cut out to make the post clearer)
C
D
A 9 8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\!Z pulpitu\Python\VTX RE.py", line 34, in <module>
    A()
  File "D:\!Z pulpitu\Python\VTX RE.py", line 11, in A
    B()
  File "D:\!Z pulpitu\Python\VTX RE.py", line 18, in B
    C()
#<...> (a couple of lines that I cut out to make the post clearer, screenshot below)
  File "D:\!Z pulpitu\Python\VTX RE.py", line 11, in A
    B()
  File "D:\!Z pulpitu\Python\VTX RE.py", line 17, in B
    print('B')
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while pickling an object
```

The question is: Can I somehow end/exit/quit/close/forget all the iterations of `B()`, `C()` and `D()` when I am in `A()` (more specifically where "# End all () except for A" is located) without resetting the values `AB` and `CD`? And will it solve the `RecursionError`?

Cause as far as I am aware, while `D()` ends itself cause it doesn't call any other recursion, `B()` and `C()` are still running in the background waiting for their called functions to finish so they can get to `print('B2')` and `print('C2')` respectively, taking unnecessary memory (which, with higher recursionlimit and more complicated objects can cause a `MemoryError`)

Comment: Huh? This doesn't make sense - there's no pickling here, and you'd get a RecursionError *way* sooner if you manually set the recursion limit to 1 like that.

Comment: Were you trying to implement a text adventure game, or something with a similar state machine structure and temptation to transition states by calling a function for a new state? That's not a good approach. (Text adventure games are one of the standard newbie projects that are actually a *really bad* fit for a newbie project.)

Comment: What I'm trying to create is a macro (or clicker) for a browser game that works using pixel color detection, where it enters loops (eg. while EndLoop==0) taking Screengrab every 0.2 seconds and depending what appears on the screen the script would either press a button, exit a loop, switch to another object (eg BattleEnded()) or enter a ErrorList() if nothing happened in those 0.5 seconds. After 9-10 hours however I got a MemoryError (despite using 64bit python) and I assumed the problem posted there might've been the cause

Comment: "switch to another object (eg BattleEnded())" - first, you're mixing up objects and functions. Second, that's a bad mechanism for state transitions. Try using a dispatcher instead - when you want to transition from the function for handling one state to the function for handling another state, the first function `return`s information to a dispatcher that the dispatcher uses to call the second function, instead of the first function calling the second function directly.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I found a way to make it work thanks to the comments by *user2357112 supports Monica* and a bit of tinkering.

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(1)

AB,CD=0,0
RunFunction=1
Run=1

def A():
    global AB,RunFunction
    AB+=1
    print('A',AB,CD)
    RunFunction=2;Block=1 #Old B()
    if Block!=1:
        print('A2')

def B():
    global AB,RunFunction
    AB+=1
    print('B')
    RunFunction=3;Block=1 #Old C()
    if Block!=1:
        print('B2')

def C():
    global CD,RunFunction
    CD+=1
    print('C')
    D()
    RunFunction=1;Block=1 #Old A()
    if Block!=1:
        print('D2')

def D():
    global CD
    CD+=1
    print('D')
    return CD

while Run==1:
    if RunFunction==1:
        A()
    if RunFunction==2:
        B()
    if RunFunction==3:
        C()
    if RunFunction==0:
        Run=0
```

Currently it's still running with AB and CD being over 45000(compared to previous 9 and 8)

Comment: Part of the purpose of an answer is to be helpful to others with the same question. Focus on explaining the process you used to get from there to here, as opposed to just showing the code.